# run a script by double-clicking the executable file

Tags: command-line, bash, executable

I want to run a script by doubleclicking the executable file. I tried this:

filename: myscript.sh
script to run: `run this script`

I making the myscript.sh executable by rightclick  and checking: "allow executing file as program" but I cannot get it to work. Everything that happens when I doubleclicking the file its content displays in the default application, in my case in GNU emacs.

How can I execute the script? This seemed easy but I cannot find a working solution.

Im running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Your questions should show the *actual* contents of the file that you double-click. It might be as simple as a typo. It might not.

Comment: okey here is the content:
`./ngrok tcp 4000` which runs ngrok on port 4000. Works fine when running this in terminal

Comment: First problem: You're not using a full path.